# Change the RequestFormat globally for every routes in Symfony 2 application

Tags: php, symfony, format, routes

Is there a way to change the default `html` RequestFormat for all my routes in the application?

This might work, but I need to set this to each individual route:

```
article_show:
  pattern:  /articles/{culture}/{year}/{title}.{_format}
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Article:show, _format: %global_format% }
```

Comment: This may helpful for you http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/routing.html#advanced-routing-example